# How to remove unwanted namespaces from xmlns in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

First, I want to start off that I am really new with stackoverflow. I'm normally a viewer and this is my first time to ask here. Second, please do excuse me if there are terminologies, which I might later use incorrectly or if I am asking in the wrong place. Lastly, I would appreciate it if everyone would use less, or possibly, no negative comments or statements, and if there are less links (to answer my question) and instead more explanation.

So, I've been working on a system. However I'm having trouble with giving request to a wsdl. Normally, I get enough namespaces for me to provide the needed information to get the proper response. However, in my case with this specific wsdl, I'm getting a lot of namespaces. I've tried using soapUI to see if I would get a response, but the problem here is that, it works if I remove enough number of namespaces.

Here is a sample:

```
<qr2:Envelope 
    xmlns:qr1="http://qr1/sample" 
    xmlns:qr2="http://qr2/sample" 
    xmlns:qr3="http://qr3/sample" 
    xmlns:qr4="http://qr4/sample" 
    xmlns:qr5="http://qr5/sample" 
    xmlns:qr6="http://qr6/sample">
    xmlns:qr7="http://qr7/sample">
    xmlns:qr8="http://qr8/sample">
    xmlns:qr9="http://qr9/sample">
    xmlns:qr10="http://qr10/sample">
    xmlns:qr11="http://qr11/sample">
    <qr2:Header>           
    </qr2:Header>
    <qr2:Body>      
    </qr2:Body>
</qr2:Envelope>
```

What I want to happen is to lessen the number of namespaces. In my sample above, instead of getting *eleven namespaces*, I want it to have, say five, as so:

```
<qr2:Envelope 
    xmlns:qr1="http://qr1/sample" 
    xmlns:qr2="http://qr2/sample" 
    xmlns:qr3="http://qr3/sample" 
    xmlns:qr4="http://qr4/sample" 
    xmlns:qr5="http://qr5/sample">
    <qr2:Header>           
    </qr2:Header>
    <qr2:Body>      
    </qr2:Body>
</qr2:Envelope>
```

Is there a way for me to do this using node.js? 
I'm already at this point of my code:

```
soap.createClient(https://sampleLinkOf.wsdl, wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {

}
```

I'd appreciate an answer instead of a workaround (deleting files, downloading files, etc).